# Swift: Create circle with animation

Tags: swift, geometry

I'm new here.

I'm trying to create falling circle objects through UIDynamicAnimator.  However, it does not look real enough.

1) Each circle object was having "space" in between. Not sure if my circle objects are created correctly.

2) Some circle object on top appears to be stuck at the top, not falling down.

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks a lot.

For clearer picture, refer to this link for image:
http://postimg.org/image/l6a84nj69/

```
var circle : UIView?
var animator:UIDynamicAnimator? = nil;
let gravity = UIGravityBehavior()
let collider = UICollisionBehavior()
let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior()

func addcircle(location: CGRect) {
    let newCircle = UIView(frame: location)
    newCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    newCircle.layer.cornerRadius = newBox.frame.width / 2
    newCircle.clipsToBounds = true

    view.insertSubview(newBox, atIndex: 0)
    circle = newCircle
}

func animateCircle() {
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView:self.view);
    animator?.addBehavior(collider)

    gravity.addItem(circle!);
    gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 0.5)
    animator?.addBehavior(gravity);

    collider.addItem(circle!)
    collider.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    animator?.addBehavior(collider)

    bounce.addItem(circle!)
    bounce.elasticity = 0.5
    animator?.addBehavior(bounce)

}
```